# I'm having trouble with creating second thread for a multi-threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, semaphore

I am trying to write a multi-threaded program with two threads; the first will update a random-access file after a "new" command is prompted, and the second accepts the commands "new" or "end", and sends it to the first thread.  I wanted to use a queue controlled by a semaphore, which is what I have written below.  I just don't know how to associate the other thread.  The one thread should produce strings from user command and insert into the queue, and the other thread retrieves the strings from the queue to write them to the direct-access file. Can anyone help chime in how to get the thread started?

```
package multi_threaded_producer_consumer;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MTQueue {

    private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
    private java.util.Queue<String> statQ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public MTQueue(){
        statQ = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public void MTPut(String qe) {
        try {
            sem.acquire();
            statQ.offer(qe);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {

        } finally {
            sem.release();
        }
    }

    public String MTGet() {
        String retVal = new String();
        try {
            sem.acquire();
            retVal = statQ.poll();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {

        } finally {
            sem.release();
        }
        return retVal;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Are you literally just asking how to write a thread in Java?  It's new Thread(myRunnable).start().  Where myRunnable is a class with a run function that does whatever you want that thread to do.  If you're asking something else, try to be more clear.

Comment: @GabeSechan Do I put it in a separate class, or add it within what I have already written? These are probably dumb questions, but I really don't understand the reasoning to use of multi-threading at all

Comment: Swallowing `InterruptedException` (or any other exception) is a _very_ bad habit.  If you don't expect your program to be interrupted, and you don't care what happens if it is interrupted, then the least you should do is `throw new RuntimeException(ex);`

Comment: Your `finally` clause will call `sem.release();` even if the semaphore was never acquired (e.g., if an interrupt happens).  That is almost certainly not what you want.  You'll need two `try` blocks to do it right:  The first one should be a try/catch to deal with the possible InterruptedException, and then the second one should be a try/finally to insure that the semaphore gets released.

Comment: How to start a thread:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help chime in how to get the thread started?

Sure.  With a basic thread you must create a `Runnable` class for the thread to run.  Here's a [good tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Here's an example of the code for your producer:

```
// queue must be final for the Runnable classes to use it
final MTQUeue queue = new MTQueue();
...
// create a new producer thread and start it
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       queue.MTPut("new");
       queue.MTPut("end");
    }
}).start();
...
// create a new consumer thread and start it
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Got command: " + queue.MTGet());
       System.out.println("Got command: " + queue.MTGet());
    }
}).start();
```

Couple of other comments about your code in no order:

- I assume this is an academic project.  Otherwise take a look at `LinkedBlockingQueue` which does this for you.
- `MTPut()` and `MTGet()` methods should probably be just `put()` and `get()`.  The MT is in the class name.
- `statQ.offer(...)` should probably be `statQ.add(...)`.  The `offer()` method is only for queues that are limited.  The `LinkedQueue` is not one of those.
- `String retVal = new String();` the `new String()` is not needed and can be removed.  Really you could do a `return statQ.poll();` and not have a `retVal`.
- Catching `InterruptedException ex` and ignoring it is really bad practice.   When you catch it you should always at least interrupt the current thread:

  ```
  } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
       // always a good pattern to re-interrupt the current thread
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       // since the thread was interrupted we should return or something
       return;
  ```